# How to store JavaDStream<String> to Hive table in spark using Java?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, spark-streaming

I am receiving the messages from Kafka server into JavaDStream object. Now i want to store the messages into hive table. How can i do that?

Code snippet for receiving messages from Kafka stream:

```
JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, zookeperIp, consumerGroup,
            topic);

JavaDStream<String> messageData = kafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {

    @Override
    public String call(Tuple2<String, String> message) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return message._2;
    }

});
```

Schema for table in Hive:

```
create external table sample(value STRING);
```

I am using spark 2.1.0 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please take a look at these official programming guides.

> [You can easily use DataFrames and SQL operations on streaming data](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations)
>
> and [Spark SQL also supports reading and writing data stored in Apache Hive](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables)

Comment: Thanks  @zhang-yuan , I got it worked by following the documents